# Create and Share a Set of Useful Data Site Queries for The Site

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

It is possible for someone familiar site data querying to create some useful set of queries for our site and share them here.

This might be useful for many of the site users.

Also feel free to request for particular useful queries or help in creating them.

This is a follow up on this answer: https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/287/295

Comment: You can browse popular queries [on Data SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/buddhism/queries?order_by=popular) and run them on any site you like. Might be good to curate a list here though if you find some things useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Find questions which have only low-voted answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/buddhism/query/226014/find-questions-with-few-answers?MUpvotes=1&NAnswers=1).

I didn't work out how to edit the description of the query (so the description is wrong).

Choosing N=1 and M=1 will find questions which don't have any answers with 2 or more votes (it will return questions which have any number of answers with 1 vote or less).

Comment: Great stuff. Let me have look.

Comment: Does MUpvotes mens the maximum upvotes? What does NAnswers mean?

Comment: N is the number of answers which have M upvotes. E.g. "N=2, M=3" specifies that you want questions which satisfy the following condition: "there are fewer than two answers with more than 3 upvotes each".